# how to create tf.data.Dataset that maps random numbers?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I am lost on how to use tf.data.Dataset to propagate random state of tf.random_uniform(). The following tensorflow snippet speaks for itself:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def fn1(x):
    z = tf.random_uniform( () )
    return x + z

d1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.zeros(100))
d2 = d1.map(fn1)
d3 = d2.map(lambda x:x)

d4 = tf.data.Dataset.zip( (d2,d3) )

it = d4.make_one_shot_iterator()
fetch = it.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        X = sess.run(fetch)
        if X[0] != X[1]:
            raise RuntimeError("Not same.")
```

The last assertion fails. It seems to me the two dataset, d2 and d3, has its own random seed, although the d3 maps the elements of d2 with identity function. How can I make the last assertion holds?

Comment: You could add a random seed here: `z = tf.random_uniform([], seed=0)`

Comment: One issue with adding a random seed is that it might not work when `num_parallel_calls > 1` (when using `d2.map(fn1, num_parallel_calls=4` for instance).

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13932 for details